# Creating Filter Form in Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i am trying to filter the data that is presented in my Index action by using scope.

I have defined it as so in `profile.rb`

```
scope :fees_to, -> (fees_to) { where("fees_to <= ?", "#{fees_to}") }
```

It works perfectly fine in rails console, i can do `Profile.fees_to(50)` for example and it returns all profiles that has fees_to that are less than 50.

What i would like to know is how do i create this input filter method in my index views?

In `profiles_controller.rb` for Index action, the code is as follows:

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.where(nil)
  @profiles = @profiles.fees_to(params[:fees_to]) if params[:fees_to].present?
end
```

I've tried collecting the information in my index view in various ways, all to know avail.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try `@profiles = Profile.fees_to(params[:fees_to]) if params[:fees_to].present?` instead of `@profiles = @profiles.fees_to(params[:fees_to]) if params[:fees_to].present?`

Comment: @Pavan could you kindly explain the difference between using `Profile.` instead of `@profile`? Additionally i'm not very clear on how i'm supposed to render my form for collection. I'm currently trying `<% form_for @profiles do |f| %>` but it renders an error.

Comment: Scopes are class methods. They should be called on a class like `ClassName.ScopeName`.

Comment: Its perfectly valid to construct scopes in several steps @Pavan.

Comment: @max does that mean the code in my controller is fine? Do you think you could help me with rendering the view for the form?

Comment: Kind of - `User.where(nil)` is a pretty weird way to do `User.all`. But otherwise it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update: This answer is completely obsolete. Use [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) for both kinds of forms in Rails 5+

Usually when creating forms in rails you use form_for to create a form is bound to a single model instance for example: `form_for(@thing)`.

However when constructing something like a search query or filters you just want a plain old form without any data binding since the goal is not to create or modify a resource.

```
<%= form_tag(profiles_path, method: :get) do %>
  <% label_tag 'fees_to', 'Maximum fee' %>
  <% number_field_tag 'fees_to' %>
  <% submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
  @profiles = @profiles.fees_to(params[:fees_to]) if params[:fees_to].present?
end
```

---

> explain the difference between using Profile. instead of @profile?

`Profile` is a constant - which in this case contains the class `Profile`.
`@profile` is a instance variable - in this context it belongs to the controller and will most likely be `nil` since it is the index action.

```
Profile.fees_to(50) # calls the class method `fees_to` on `Profile`.
@profile.fees_to(50) # will most likely give a `NoMethodError`.
```

However when you are doing:

```
@profiles = Profile.all
@profiles = @profiles.fees_to(params[:fees_to]) if params[:fees_to].present?
```

What is happening is that you are just chaining scope calls like in this example:

```
@users = User.where(city: 'London')
             .where(forename: 'John')
```

except that instead of chaining you are mutating the variable `@profiles`.

Comment: hi max thanks for providing a solution. however the filter is not working. i can see this line in the server log `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "Fees_to"=>"10"}` but it doesn't seem to be doing `Profiles.all.fees_to(10)` which works in my rails console.

Comment: Try using `number_field_tag 'fees_to'`. For some reason it changed the case when using a symbol.

Comment: just realised i made a typo under 'fees_to'. works perfectly fine! thank you so much!